# Accessing ARM peripheral registers through structures

Tags: c++, assembly, struct, arm

I want to make my own library for ARM Cortex-M3 enabled devices. Currently writing to a register looks like this:

```
(*((unsigned int volatile * const)(0x400E0410))) = (1 << 11) | (1 << 12);
```

Where `0x400E0410` is the address of a 32-bit peripheral register (in this case the address of Power Management Controller's 'Peripheral Clock Enable Register').

So I wish to abstract peripherals into `struct` so it's a lot more user-friendly, readable, and allows for autocompletion inside the IDE. The previous example would then look like so:

```
PMC.PCER = PORTB.ID | PORTC.ID;
```

I can't use `volatile` on `struct` or on its members, otherwise (to my knowledge) that'd always include the struct in the final code even if its not actually being used for anything in the code. I also noticed that even if the struct is `name-less` and all its members have been initialised as const values, the compiler makes a constructor for it and stores it in RAM instead of the FLASH which is really suboptimal.

Optimally I'd also want the `struct` approach to generate assembly code like this (disassembly of first example):

[image: first example disassembly]

Instead of code like this that's reading struct variables from RAM (my approach using volatile members inside a struct):

[image: second example disassembly]

How could I implement this while not compromising for program size or performance?

**EDIT: C++ code for my approach, u32v is an unsigned volatile 32bit integer, u32c is an unsigned const 32bit integer**
[image: my code]

Comment: I would recommend strongly against using structs across compile domains.  But there are countless examples of what you are trying to do.  All of these volatile approaches are going to carry the side effects of using volatile.

Comment: @old_timer Do you have a link to such examples?

Comment: st.com, github.com

Comment: your first approach looks the cleanest if you desire a volatile based approach. you can wrap all of the stuff on the left into a define #define SOME_REGISTER (*((unsigned int volatile * const)(0x400E0410)))  .... SOME_REGISTER = (1 << 11) | (1 << 12);

Comment: Despite old_timer's dislike of using structs for register access, most of use are willing to dance along that edge by using CMSIS definitions for chip registers. Is there some reason you are not?

Comment: Please show your struct approach that generated that code to see if it is the approach.

Comment: @andymango I never used CMSIS, but I'd like to write my own library for accessing registers and controlling the device in order to get a lot of experience.

Comment: @old_timer I added a picture of my approach in the edit

Comment: @old_timer I also though about that approach, but that doesn't allow for auto-completion, That's why I'm trying to go with the `struct` approach. If it's not possible to use `struct` in this way then I guess I'll be forced with that option.

Comment: Given than this is C++ a class or struct used as a namespace container for inline accessor and mutator functions that wrap all of the ugliness might be way to go - which ought to yield optimal code.

Comment: As @andymango said, this is exactly what CMSIS does, so if you want to see a good example of the technique look at the CMSIS code. You talk about "include the struct in the final code"...the struct will be in **hardware** so of course it is in the final code. I don't understand why you are trying to reinvent the wheel while ignoring all of the wheel development that has come before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I didn't think about this before, but `volatile` inside a function is only read by the compiler when you use that function. So I just made a struct using `operator=(int)` and `operator int()` overloads.

When using optimisation flags the compiler discards everything that the user doesn't use, which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

> So I wish to abstract peripherals into struct so it's a lot more user-friendly ...

Many "MCAL" packets (hardware abstraction used in the automotive industry) do it like this. Example:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned IN; /* offset 0 */
    unsigned _unused1[3];
    unsigned OUT; /* offset 0x10 */
    unsigned _unused2[3];
    unsigned DIR; /* offset 0x20 */
} PortStruct;

#define PORTA (*(volatile PortStruct *)0x80001000))
#define PORTB (*(volatile PortStruct *)0x80002000))
```

... so you can access the peripheral registers the following way:

```
PORTA.OUT |= (1<<4);
```

I have also seen that such a structure has been declared as variable:

```
extern volatile PortStruct PORTA;
```

... and the "variable" was defined at a fixed address (0x80001000 in the example) by using compiler-specific keywords, hand-written assembly code or special instructions in the linker configuration file.

> I can't use `volatile` ... on its members

There seem to be compilers that don't even allow `volatile` for members but only for the entire `struct`.

> ... the compiler makes a constructor for it and stores it in RAM instead of the FLASH which is really suboptimal.

The way you are using these `struct`s look a bit strange to me.

I just tried the following code with the GCC tool chain (C, not C++) for ARM and optimization switched on:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned hello;
    unsigned world;
    unsigned foo;
    unsigned bar;
    unsigned PCER;
    unsigned example;
} PortType;

#define PMC (*(volatile PortType *)0x400E0400)

void test(void)
{
    PMC.PCER = 5;
}
```

The result (here the object file):

```
00000000 <test>:
   0:   4b01      ldr    r3, [pc, #4] ; (8 <test+0x8>)
   2:   2205      movs   r2, #5
   4:   611a      str    r2, [r3, #16]
   6:   4770      bx     lr
   8:   400e0400 .word  0x400e0400
```

No initialization code, constructors or similar were generated.

I also tried the `extern volatile PortStruct` approach:

```
typedef struct {
    ...
} PortType;

extern volatile PortType PMC;

void test(void)
{
    PMC.PCER = 5;
}
```

As already written, either some hand-written assembly code some information in the linker script would be neccessary to define the address of the pseudo-variable "PMC" as 0x400E0400.

I tried both approaches (assembly and linker script): The result was exactly the same as with the `#define` approach.

**EDIT**

I also compiled the code with the C++ compiler instead of the C compiler: The resulting code is the same.

Comment: This works, but when putting volatile on a struct it includes the whole struct in memory, as opposed to only keeping the parts of it that the user actually uses in their code.